# Delaying API calls with debouncing not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debouncing

I have gone through several posts but, none useful. So, in a small React project which displays all vegetable images. It also has search box which will fetch relevant vegetable card. I'm trying to implement `debouncing` function but, not working as expected. Please follow the code below.

```
// useDeounce function called but, doesn't work
let newAllData = useCallback(useDebounce(searchData, 1000), []);

const getAllData = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        "https://mocki.io/v1/ffbc0f6f-342f-459d-93b4-5921f723b50e"
      );
      setLoading(false);
      setNewData(data);
      console.log("NEW DATA", data); // This gets called on every type of text
    } catch (e) {
      setError(e);
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

useEffect(() => {
    getAllData();
  }, []);

  const handleSearch = (value) => {
    const event = value;

    setSearchData(event);
  };

  const allData = useMemo(() => {

    // the variable with debounce -> newAllData is used here
    if (!newAllData) return newData;

    console.log("NEW DATA HERE", newData);
    return (
      newData &&
      newData?.filter(
        (data) =>
          (data.name.toLowerCase() && data.name.toLowerCase()).search(
            newAllData.toLowerCase()
          ) !== -1 ||
          (data.title.toLowerCase() &&
            data.title.toLowerCase().search(newAllData.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
      )
    );
  }, [searchData, newData]);
```

As you can see from above code, `getAllData` fetches the data from API and is called in `useEffect`,  `allData` is a memoized function which will prevent it from re-rendering, but, still on every tpye, API is called, hence with debouncing may reduce the calls and delay it. Please observe debouncing code.

```
const useDebounce = (val, delay) => {
  const [debValue, setDebValue] = useState(val);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebValue(val);
    }, delay);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(handler);
    };
  }, [val, delay]);

  return debValue;
};
```

What could be the appropriate solution. Since, this is the major concern as API calls, may cost performance issue. Any suggestion highly appreciated.

CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-faraday-j85m9n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove the `useCallback` that wraps your `useDebounce` hook. Thats unnecessary.

```js
let newAllData =useDebounce(searchData, 1000);
```

Second, update your `useMemo` dependency array

```js
const allData = useMemo(() => {

    // the variable with debounce -> newAllData is used here
    if (!newAllData) return newData;

    console.log("NEW DATA HERE", newData);
    return (
      newData &&
      newData?.filter(
        (data) =>
          (data.name.toLowerCase() && data.name.toLowerCase()).search(
            newAllData.toLowerCase()
          ) !== -1 ||
          (data.title.toLowerCase() &&
            data.title.toLowerCase().search(newAllData.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
      )
    );
     // Change the dependency here from [searchData, newData] to [newAllData, newData]

  }, [newAllData, newData]);
```

Everything should work now as expected !

Comment: No effect, still it calls repeatedly

Comment: I wen throught your sandbox code. You are not making repetitive API call. You are calling the API once on mount . I think you are confusing your `console.log("NEW DATA", newData);` at line 56 with the similar type of log at line 27 inside API call function. They are different. Remove the console log from line 56.

Comment: Ok but, is the debounce function actually working, how can we ensure? Because the moment I type something in text box images are shown immediately

Comment: Your debounce is working fine. If you type first enough in the search box, you will see, the  list below is not changing. It changes after you stop typing.

Comment: yes now I observed..,. working fine... Thanks